blazor after visual studio update throws some strange JS warnings
After update visual studio to 17.11.3, in almost every file that i opened with visual studio threw some warning:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning (active)    TS1109  (JS) Expression expected.   Miscellaneous   D:\xxx\Components\Core\DialogConfirmComponent.razor__virtual.html__virtual.js   9   


As on screen

Is it some .net bug ? or i should do something with it? no idea what it is this _virtual.html_virtual.js? guess some temp file?
before update there was no such things...?
thanks and regards
Edit:
Minimal Reproducible Example

Have 17.11.3 Visual Studio
Dotnet new install MudBlazor.Templates
New project  - MudBlazor Web APP (server rendering mode / global)
Open counter component. delete all.
Paste into this counter component

    <MudButton Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Primary" DropShadow="false" OnClick="@(()=>blabla())">Validate</MudButton>
@code {

    public void blabla()
    {
        
    }

}


Save and see the warnings


I had a test in my side by upgrading the VS to 17.11.3 version but didn't get your warning. I'm afraid we'd better to go to the .razor__virtual.html__virtual.js file(if we can) and DialogConfirmComponent.razor to see whether there's syntax warning in these files. By the way, since this warning is caused by upgrade, could you please try to delete the bin and obj and the .vs folder then rebuild your solution to see whether the warning still exist? .vs is hidden by default and is in the same folder as the .sln file laies.

hi thx but i checked / deleting this folders chhange nothing. please help me track this if Yu known how / there is no such file as .razor__virtual.html__virtual.js / where to look for it / it is not my file / it is something that VS is creating somwhere probablt thanks and regards

I could only say this file might be generated by Visual Studio when Razor components are compiled and I didn't find any blazor document to say about it so that I can't find them too. Here I want to double confirm with you that the warnings look related to several components, have you tried to delete the js method part in those components then rebuild the app, and see whether the warnings still exist?

yes and this components DO NOT HAVE any js in them that i  wrote. components use mudblazor - maybe there is some js inside of mudblazor components. and Yes this warning apear in almost  ANY component that i open (doubleclick)  so list is bigger with every opened tab with file...

Does it load & use your MudBlazor correctly? What's in the generated html? etc.

Better, but step 3&4 should be something like replace <Button ..> with <MudButton ...>

Step 2 is important, the global should have made it work.

yes mudblazor loads correctly / updated minimal step 4  / did You managed to get same warning ? / please explain more "Step 2 is important, the global should have made it work. –
" / i do not understand

i downgraded to visual studio 17.10.5 and NO WARNINGS so issue is only in 17.11.3.

ok i found it
for future searchers
from version of visual studio 17.11.3
 OnClick="@(async () => await Validate())">
i causing this isasue
 @onclick="@(async () => await Validate())">
or
@onclick="Validate"
is not throwing it.
but the OnClick should also work as it is part of the api
https://mudblazor.com/api/button#properties
please if someone known - why this is throwing it now? i added minimal example in first post/question
i downgraded to visual studio 17.10.5 and NO WARNINGS so issue is only in 17.11.3.
so it is issue with VS
i opened case for them
https://github.com/dotnet/razor/issues/10896
edit.
yes it is their bug and slould e fixed.

Side note, try @onclick="Validate". Shorter and more efficient.

thx added but why this was valid before this update?

Yes, OnClick should work (the same way). We don't have enough info to see why it's not. Try setting up a [mre]

ok as i now finaly known what is causing it - i added minimal steps to have this minimal reproducible example - please se updated question ;)

I got exact same problem on vs17.11.5 with BRAND NEW Blazor project.
I just modified the contact form and now I got that JS error on the virtual page.
Since the virtual js is created on the fly when the project run, there is no way to debug or fix the file... hence it seem to be a vs bug.
for me, removing the @ fixed it in this:
<ValidationMessage For="@(() => Input.Message)" />

to
<ValidationMessage For="() => Input.Message" />

